# Oracle 12c impdp ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, impdp

I'm new with Oracle and I'm just trying to import a dump file.  I'm able to create my container database, however when I go to run `impdp gy/gy@mygy file=C:\app\impdir\EL1.DMP` I am getting `ORA-12154`.

This is the script I used to create my pluggable db, now I think I just don't understand how to connect.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE mygy ADMIN USER gy identified by "gy"
DEFAULT TABLESPACE mygytbs
DATAFILE 'C:\app\me\product\21c\oradata\XE\XEPDB1\mygy.dbf'
SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON
FILE_NAME_CONVERT=(
'C:\app\me\product\21c\oradata\XE\pdbseed\',
'C:\app\me\product\21c\oradata\XE\XEPDB2\');
alter session set container=mygy;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY impdir AS 'C:\app\impdir';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY impdir TO gy;
GRANT DBA,CONNECT TO gy;
```

impdb

```
impdp gy/gy@mygy file=C:\app\impdir\EL1.DMP


Import: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Nov 22 11:43:20 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDI-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Comment: The TNS alias `mygy` is not defined in your `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` file.

Comment: @pmdba thanks!!! now i am getting UDI-01017: operation generated ORACLE error 1017
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied  isn't impdp gy/gy@mygy correct?

Comment: I just figured it out, now I have all other issues with the dump file, but yay!  If you put that as answer i'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TNS alias mygy is not defined in your `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` file, so the Oracle client doesn't know where to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Tns not define :

1. Register tns on databas

   ```
   sql> alter system set local_listener='address=(protocol=tcp)(host= hostname)(port=port_number))' scope=both;
   Sql> alter system register;
   ```
2. Add service name with netca